# How to force Name pattern for Hostnames in Azure policies?

Tags: json, azure, pattern-matching, hostname, policy

Microsoft provides a JSON-Template for an Azure policy:

```html
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Hostname pattern with match condition.",
        "description": "Enforce a naming pattern on Hostnames with the match condition.",
        "mode": "All",
        "parameters": {
            "namePattern": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "description": "Pattern to use for Hostnames. Can include ? for letters and # for numbers."
                }
            }
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "not": {
                    "field": "name",
                    "match": "[parameters('namePattern')]"
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "deny"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this JSON checks for ALL resources in Azure (NICs, Disks, etc). I want only a Policy for **Hostnames**.

I think I have somewhere to inject the qualifier for `/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/` - but where? Every try ends up in an invalid JSON-File. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the types of resources by specifying a check on the type field. We need to add "allOf" because we need all the conditions to be satisfied for a deny. 
I think below change to your policy rule should work.

```
"policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "allof":[
                {
                   "field": "type",
                   "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachines"
                },
                {
                   "not": {
                     "field": "name",
                     "match": "[parameters('namePattern')]"
                   }
                }
             ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
        }
    }
```